# comparing off_t and ssize_t with other types

Tags: c

I am new to C and recently ran into some trouble with mismatching data types and their memory allocation.  I am writing a very simple program to calculate the xor checksum of a file read using Linux system calls.

My question is this:  Do I need to be concerned with unpredictable results when comparing an **off_t** or **ssize_t** with a **long** or **int**?

For example:

```
long i;
for(i = 0; i < fileStat.st_size; i++)
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

and also:

```
ssize_t i;
for(i = 0; i < fileStat.st_size; i++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing types of the same signedness but different size with one-another works, as the smaller type is extended to the larger type. Comparing types of different signedness is problematic as you could get wrong results if the signed type is not larger than the unsigned type and the signed number is negative. It is a good idea to make sure the signed number is not negative at first:

```
signed_t a;
unsigned_t b;

/* instead of */
if (a < b)
    /* ... */

/* use */
if (a < 0 || a < b)
    /* ... */
```

Comment: _Comparing types of different signedness is problematic as you could get wrong results if both types have the same size and the signed number is negative_   I don't quite understand this line . Can you please give any example ?

Comment: @ameyCU If both types have the same size, the signed type is converted to an unsigned type before conversion (cf. ISO 9899:2011§6.3.1.8). If the object of signed type is negative, it is converted into something positive which can yield wrong results.

Comment: By _signedness_ you meant sign or unsigned type . I misunderstood if type is signed but number one is `+` and second is `-` .

Comment: @ameyCU Yes. This is why I wrote “types of the same signedness,” not “values of the same signedness.”

Comment: While FUZxxi’s answer is correct, the real solution for these examples is to use a type at least as wide as the type you’re comparing to for your counter. Otherwise, in an environment with 32-bit pointers, ints or longs and 64-bit file offsets, your program will break for files more than 2GiB in size. Just use `off_t i`.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard states that the `long` type is large enough to represent the constant `LONG_MAX`, which must be at least 2147483647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1). If we take this lower bound as the value of `LONG_MAX`, then it's possible that it isn't large enough. It's one less than 2 GiB, after all.

`ssize_t` isn't in the C standard, but is defined in the POSIX standard. It must be large enough to represent the constant `SSIZE_MAX`, which must be at least 32767 (2<sup>15</sup>-1). Don't rely on this type either.

On my machine, `long` and `ssize_t` are both 4 bytes. You can verify the sizes yourself using the `sizeof` operator. You may get different results. If you want your program to be portable, don't rely on something implementation-specific.

Lastly, if you really don't want to use those typedefs, I recommend using the `unsigned long long` type. It's large enough to represent the constant `ULLONG_MAX`, which must be at least 18446744073709551615 (2<sup>64</sup>-1).

See also: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html

Comment: I don't see how this answer is helpful. All the boundaries you specify are lower boundaries for the actual boundaries. For example, on my system (amd64 Linux), `ssize_t` is a `signed long` and comparing an `ssize_t` to an `unsigned long long` can lead to problems.

Comment: @FUZxxl: *Sigh...* the point is, you can't rely on any of the integer types to be a certain size. At least confirm the limits through the aforementioned constants before making any assumptions about the types in your program. Also, I gave an example of these limits. `long` and `ssize_t` are both 4 bytes on my machine. Not really enough to represent the size of a large file!

Comment: Note: there may be some misunderstandings because of how the OP asked the question. You're right that you shouldn't compare `ssize_t` with `unsigned long long`. I'm not saying otherwise. I'm basing my answer on the examples he gave, although the underlying point (don't rely on implementation) stands.

Comment: My solution works regardless of how large the types involved are. Converting to a larger types does not work all too well, especially considering that on most platforms today `off_t` is a `signed long long`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Let's clear things up. Converting to a larger type is fine, *unless* you're converting from a signed type to an unsigned type and the former is negative. Converting from a larger type to a smaller type is problematic, however, as the result will wrap around the limit of the smaller type. The behaviour is implementation-specific, except if the types are unsigned, in which case it's a modulo operation: `i % LLONG_MAX`, for example.

Comment: What behaviour is implementation specific? Conversion of signed types? Nope, that's not true. The behaviour is completely well-defined by the standard. And again: *You can't convert to a larger type if the variable already has the largest possible type.*

Comment: Haha read the standard again. The C standard allows some freedom in the representation of signed types, which is why unsigned to signed is implementation-specific. See clause 3 of section 6.3.1.3. And sorry, your last sentence doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How are you supposed to convert a value of the largest integer type (e.g. `long long int`) to a larger type? There can't be a larger type if the value already has the largest possible type. And your remark about §6.3.1.3 is correct, but all but the most exotic platforms implement the expected behaviour for this kind of conversion (i.e. truncation).

Comment: Man what are you talking about? You're putting words in my mouth. Truncation? Just get some sleep and then come back.

Comment: My last sentence was answering to you claiming that “converting to a larger type is fine.” It's a solution where applicable but it isn't applicable if you already have the largest type. Truncation as in “just take the lowest *n* bits and throw the others away”

Comment: ... just get some sleep

Comment: If you are not interested in a fact-based discussion, there are less condescending ways to say that.

Comment: Sorry (maybe I'm the one who needs sleep). If there's anything misleading in my answer, I'll correct it. I just hope it gives the OP or anyone with similar questions at least some insight.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings about comparison between signed and unsigned integers (and other arithmetic operations), stem from the implicit conversions that occur when two operands of unlike type are combined with an operator.

There is a good chapter on this issue in the manual that accompanies the PC-Lint tool from Gimpel.

A reading of the available C standards documents in particular "integer promotions" is helpful.

eg in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf (C99) - section 6.3.1 "Arithmetic operands"

In particular, "if an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int"

Hence in such a context, "-1" will get converted to binary all-ones [implementation-dependent] as an unsigned number - potentially giving surprising results to the unwary. eg an unsigned integer quantity divided by integer "-1" will give zero.

The answer there is to cast the unsigned to a signed value before the arithmetic.

Note that sizeof() returns an unsigned value.