# Received remark as comparison between signed and unsigned operands

Tags: c

I have a "C"code snippet as below

```
int32_t A = 5;
uint32_t B = 8;
if ( A >= B )
 {
   printf("Test");
 }
```

When i build this i received an remark/warning as "comparison between signed and unsigned operands.Can any one address this issue?

Comment: you are comparing `int32_t` (signed) with `uint32_t` (unsigned). What did you expect?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `int32_t` and `uint32_t`?

Comment: What if `A` was `-5`? `B` can't be negative.. oops.

Comment: and you'll find out that `-5 > B`

Comment: My answer was added to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043908/comparing-off-t-and-ssize-t-with-other-types/45347435#45347435 due to answers on this post becoming disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok while `A` is positive and `B` is less than `2^31`.

But, if `A` is less than `0`, then unexpected behavior occurs.

`A = -1`, in memory it will be saved as `0xFFFFFFFF`.
`B = 5`, in memory it will be saved as `0x00000005`.

When you do

```
if (A < B) {
    //Something, you are expecting to be here
}
```

Compiler will compare them as unsigned 32-bit integer and your if will be expanded to:

```
if (0xFFFFFFFF < 0x00000005) {
    //Do something, it will fail.
}
```

Compiler warns you about this possible problem.

[Comparison operation on unsigned and signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/comparison-operation-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers)

Comment: It's implementatation-defined how negative numbers are saved in memory.  When you write `A < B` then there is a value conversion , `-1` is converted to `0xFFFFFFFF` (assuming 32-bit) regardless of the negative number representation.  Now, systems usually use 2's complement in order that this conversion is a no-op. But there are non 2's comp systems.

Answer (score 0):

Good, very good! You are reading and paying attention to your compiler warnings.

In your code:

```
int32_t A = 5;
uint32_t B = 8;

if ( A >= B )
{
   printf("Test");
}
```

You have `'A'` as a *signed* `int32_t` value with min/max values of `-2147483648/2147483647` and you have and *unsigned* `uint32_t` with min/max of `0/4294967295`, respectively. The compiler generates the warning to guard against cases that are always true or false based on the types involved. Here `A` can never be greater than `B` for any values in the allowable range of `B` from `2147483648 - 4294967295`. That whole swath of numbers will provide `False` regardless of the individual values involved.

Another great example would be `if ( A < B )` which produces a `TRUE` for all values of `A` from `-2147483648 - -1` because the *unsigned* type can never be less than zero.

The compiler warnings are there to *warn* that testing with these types may not provide valid comparisons for certain ranges of numbers -- that you might not have anticipated.

In the real world, if you know `A` is only holding values from `0 - 900`, then  you can simply tell the compiler that 1) you understand the warning and by your cast will 2) guarantee the values will provide valid tests, e.g.

```
int32_t A = 5;
uint32_t B = 8;

if (A >= 0 ) {
    if ( (uint32_t)A >= B )
       printf("Test");
}
else
    /* handle error */
```

If you cannot make the guarantees for **1) & 2)**, then it is time to go rewrite the code in a way you are not faced with the warning.

Two good things happened here. You had *compiler warnings* enabled, and you took the time to read and understand what the compiler was telling you. This will come up time and time again. Now you know how to approach a determination of what can/should be done.