# Detecting signed vs. unsigned comparison bugs

Tags: c

I've found an issue in some code I'm working with that I'm concerned may be a problem in several areas of the codebase. The issue has to do with signed/unsigned comparisons:

```
unsigned short u16;
short s16;
u16 = 0x8000;
s16 = u16;
if (u16 > s16) {
    /* This is what gets printed in GCC */
    printf("u16 > s16\n");
} else if (u16 == s16) {
    printf("u16 == s16\n");
} else {
    printf("u16 < s16\n");
}
```

I understand [why this is an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043908/comparing-off-t-and-ssize-t-with-other-types). Are there good ways of reliably locating this kind of issue in your codebase? Ideally, it would appear as a compiler warning or a static code analysis warning, but neither GCC nor Coverity say anything.

Comment: If you turn the compiler's warning on and make it verbose, does it generate warnings? There are also static tools out there. E.g. Look for MISRA C compliance software tools. I am not sure if you are willing to spend the money.

Comment: Do you have warnings turned on?  GCC should warn about this with `-Wsign-compare` or `-Wextra`.

Comment: surprisingly this [warns if you use int](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LSePapaYpYtD8QLD) but not [if you use short](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i0KlmYR9o2jKQjGL). This is true in both clang and gcc.

Comment: regarding: `unsigned short u16;
short s16;
u16 = 0x8000;
s16 = u16;`  this is the very reason why the compiler outputs the warning message about interaction between `signed` and `unsigned` variables

Comment: @RyanHaining: Not too suprising -- integer promotion means that the correct (signed) comparison happens for shorts, while the incorrect (unsigned) comparison happens for ints.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `-Wsign-compare` with `-Wsign-conversion`.

The first one warns you when you compare signed values with unsigned ones. The latter warns you about implicit conversions from unsigned to signed and from signed to unsigned.

In your case `-Wsign-compare` won't do anything because of integer promotion, while `-Wsign-conversion` will warn about implicit conversion in `s16 = u16`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Comment: and of course -Werror , just to make sure you fix em